# GUI MySQL program

Tags: linux, database, ubuntu, mysql

I am looking for a relatively basic way to browse a MySQL database.   I need to be able to connect to a remote database located at x.y.com.  I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and am able to connect via terminal but am looking to use a simple GUI.  Note: I need to connect with SSL.

Comment: Which o/s are you using? Should the solution be free, or do you have a budget? The more information you give, the more that we can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! You just need to connect, not more? Ah, and browse? That's a little broad. Could you give a few more details what features the GUI should offer? Must you be able to view structures (i.e. "reverse-engineer" CREATE TABLE etc., see triggers/relations like foreign keys), or just "see what's in the tables"? Do you need to add/edit entries? What else might be relevant? You might wish to check [this meta-discussion](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for hints on how to improve your question for the best chance on good answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the official [MySql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

You can also do much, much more, so why choose anything other than the official (and free) tool?

This image (from http://www.mysql.com/common/images/products/MySQL_Workbench_Mainscreen_Windows.gif, in case it is not too visible), shows SSL:
[image]